# Read a file containing 16bit signed data

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fopen

I would like to open a file (approx 400kb) containing 16bit signed data ,  do some computations (for example output[i] = input[i] - input[i-1]),  and then write the output in a new file.

I'm a bit stuck with such a simple thing in C++ : I know how to write text in files, but not raw data.  A small working example would be great!

Comment: Do you know the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the input data file (you better).

Comment: Yes : LittleEndian (Intel).

Comment: if the *reader* and writer are both le, with no intent on being portable to platforms that *aren't* this just got a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the read and write operations.

```
#include <fstream>

ifstream infile("input", ios_base::binary);
int16_t in[100], out[100];
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(in), sizeof in);
...
ofstream outfile("output", ios_base::binary);
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(out), sizeof out);
```

but still plenty to do, like error checking, dynamic allocation, endianess.

Comment: cough. reinterpret casts. cough

Comment: +1, @sehe unrelated, your profile pic is *awesome*. So many times I've had days like that.

Comment: It is Little-endian (Intel).
Thanks already a lot for answer.
Can you help me just a little bit more : testing file length, and allocate the relevant memory size (malloc)  : I always spend 4 hours for such little things, maybe you'll know in 1 minute ;) ?

Comment: @JosBas don't `malloc()`. This is C++. Use a `std::vector<int16_t>` properly resized to your file bytelen/2.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, but this is difficult for me... Would you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't... actually need to read the whole shebang, you can read it on the fly:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

bool read_word(istream& is, int16_t& value)
{
    char buf[sizeof(int16_t)];
    if (is.read(buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        memcpy(&value, buf, sizeof(value));
        return is;
    }
    return false;
}

bool write_word(ostream& os, int16_t value)
{
    char buf[sizeof(int16_t)];
    memcpy(buf, &value, sizeof(buf));
    return os.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
}

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("input.dat", ios::binary);

    int16_t previous, next;
    if (read_word(ifs, previous))
    {
        ofstream ofs("output.dat", ios::binary);
        while (read_word(ifs, next))
        {
            if (!write_word(ofs, next - previous))
                return 255;
            previous = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, your performance will likely improve if you use `readsome` or read blocks, usually of 4k size, in one go.

Comment: thanks a lot ! but it doesn't work : i'm compiling with `cl.exe /EHsc main.cpp` (Visual C++ windows)... I have this error : `main.cpp(6) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'int16_t'`

Comment: @JosBas Really? It wasn't hard to find: **[<cstdint>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)**